# Calculating F-distribution probability without tables (Hypothesis problem)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

During a total solar eclipse the temperature drops quickly as the moon passes   between the earth and the sun. These data are obtained on the drop in temperature in degrees Fahrenheit at two types of locations in southern Africa during the June 2001 eclipse:

**Mountainous terrain**: 15, 12, 16, 16, 13, 15, 11, 19, 15

**River-level terrain**: 13, 17, 19, 16, 15, 19, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24

> Is there evidence at the a = 0.20 level of significance that there is a difference in the variances in temperature drop seen in these two terrains?

This is the whole question for the one who is interested. It boils down to solving this (I think):

$P(F(10,8)>1.79)$, where $F$ denotes the F-distribution. The tables have nothing on this, how do I solve it? Do I have to do some kind of *force majeure* solution, looking at the definition of the F- distribution probability function?

Best regards //